# Android application and raspberry pi communication

Tags: java, android, python, network-programming, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project which uses Raspberry pi to feed my pet. This is my first project on Raspberry Pi. I am referring to [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Internet-Enabled-Raspberry-Pi-Pet-Feeder/) tutorial on Instructables.

The tutorial uses external switches and lcd display to control and monitor the raspberry Pi. I wish to create an android application instead which will enable me to interact with the pi without the use of buttons and screen.

The application will simply post a request over a network which the pi will listen to and run a python script. the pi will then perform the action(feed the pet) and send an acknowledgement of success back to the app.

I wish to know how this idea can be implemented and which libraries can  be vital for building the communication framework.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java networking for the app and the pi. Some basic networking tutorials on java are here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html

For the android app you can use this tutorial
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Then if the server gets a connection just run your python script like that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 you_script.py");`